# Ninject logger using NLog

Tags: c#, ninject, nlog

I've just started learning Ninject but have come across a problem with the logger. I've currently got a controller that has a service and logger injected into the constructor like so:

```
public ToolsController(IToolsService toolsService, ILogger logger)
{
    logger.Info("ToolsController Created");
    this.toolsService = toolsService;
    this.logger = logger;
}
```

The problem is on the logger.Info line (for example) in the constructor which seems to use the wrong logger, so the logger name it prints out is incorrect.

```
Tools.IGeocodeImporter: ToolsController Created
```

Below is how it is setup to get the logger name:

```
kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<Logger>().WithConstructorArgument("name", x => x.Request.ParentContext.Request.Service.FullName);
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What logger name would you have expected?

Comment: The class name of wherever the logger is. Something on the lines of: `ToolsController: ToolsController Created`

Answer (score 20):

I use the following:

```
.Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(p => LogManager.GetLogger(
                   p.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType));
```

To have the logger with the name of the class. I'm using Log4net, but I think the idea can be applied to any log as well: in fact binding to a method open you to any solution in order to create the needed instance.

Comment: This answer helped me in making the correct code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65797518/6208972

Answer (score 9):

I use a ninject extension called Ninject.Extensions.Logging.NLog2, which can be found on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Logging.nlog2) or [GitHub](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging). It handles the binding of NLog, so you don't have to do anything else than just add it to your project and remove any bindings to NLog that you have right now.

Comment: Do you know if there are any tutorials available with this library?

Comment: Check this link out  http://blog.tonysneed.com/2011/10/09/using-nlog-with-dependency-injection/

Comment: Here is the link to the extension wiki https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging/wiki

Comment: There's a new version, usable with Ninject 4.5.8+.  Ninject.Extensions.Logging.NLog4.

Answer (score 1):

As Felice mentioned you can use the same method, However for Nlog you need  a little bit change which is :

```
.Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod(p => NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(
                   p.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType));
```

Comment: Seems to be working for me - certainly gets the logger constructed.

Comment: But unfortunately, this produces logger which name is constant and belongs to the class where this statement is written.

Answer (score 1):

I think at this moment the best way is to install extensions for your logger (for NLog):

```
Install-Package Ninject.Extensions.Logging.NLog4
```

and then in you code:

```
 using var kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings(){LoadExtensions = false}, new NLogModule());
```

`new NinjectSettings(){LoadExtensions = false}` - this element is required to properly load NLogModule.

and now you are ready to get new instance of `ILogger`:

```
public class PublicPropertyLoggerClass
{
    [Inject]
    public Ninject.Extensions.Logging.ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}
```

But if you don't like installing new nuget packages, you can still use:

```
_kernel.Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod(p => LogManager.GetLogger(p.Request.Target?.Member.DeclaringType.FullName ?? typeof(App).GetType().FullName));
```

Where the `App` is your startup class.

Answers based on: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Logging/wiki/Using