# get the class name that requested Ninject service

Tags: c#, ninject, nlog

I am abstracting away NLog. So far, what I have...

```
public interface IAppLogger
{
    void Info(string message);
    void Warn(string message);
    void Error(string message, Exception error);
    void Fatal(string message);
     ....// other overload
}
```

And an Implementation of IAppLogger using NLog

```
public class NLogLogger : IAppLogger
{
    private readonly NLog.Logger _logger;

    public NLogLogger([CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = "")
    {
       _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(callerFilePath);
    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {
       _logger.Info(message);
    }

    public void Warn(string message)
    {
       _logger.Warn(message);
    }
    .....// and others
 }
```

And Console Application that uses this service

```
public class Program
{
    private static IAppLogger Log { get; set; }

    private static void Main()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        Log = kernel.Get<IAppLogger>();

        Log.Info("Application Started");
        Log.Warn("Developer: Invalid date format");
        Log.Error("Divid by zero error", new DivideByZeroException());

        Console.WriteLine("\nDone Logging");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And a dependency Injection using Ninject

```
public class NinjectConfig : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IAppLogger>().To<NLogLogger>()
         .WithConstructorArgument("callerFilePath", GetParentTypeName);
    }

    private static string GetParentTypeName(IContext context)
    {
        return context.Request.ParentRequest.Service.FullName;
    }
}
```

so far so good. But When I run the application, Ninject keeps returning **NULL for context.Request.ParentRequest**. I also tried it with context.Request.Target........ **Still it returns NULL for context.Request.Target**. What am I doing wrong. Help me out please!!!!

Comment: Check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457623/how-to-get-implementing-type-during-ninject-dependency-resolve

Comment: @dbugger So what I understand from the link you suggested is that, ParentContext or Target will be null if I accessed Ninject service through IResolutionRoot.Get<IAppLogger>() like I did on Console application above. GOT IT!!. Thank you very much.

Comment: But is there a way that a class that get the injection to notify it self to Ninject service using IResolutionRoot so that ParentContext won't be null

Comment: "I am abstracting away NLog." That's not abstraction away, that's copying the exact API. Consider [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646820/logger-wrapper-best-practice) instead.

Comment: @Steven thanks. I like your answer on the link you gave me.

Comment: you will to adapt the binding if you want the binding to work when the logger is ctor-injected as well as when it is created by `IResolutionRoot.Get<IAppLogger>()`. One way is two separate bindings with a when condition (which checks whether `IContext.Request.Target`). When null use a ctor-parameter which needs to be supplied by `Get<IAppLogger>(.. parameter goes here...)`. Parameter could be a `ConstructorArgument` for example.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit are you suggesting like 

kernel.Get<IAppLogger>(
                    new ConstructorArgument("callerFilePath", param)
               );

Comment: yes. You can put it in a factory so you don't have to do the same thing over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748455/ninject-logger-using-nlog) that may work for you, give this a try:

```
public class NLogLogger : IAppLogger
{
    private readonly NLog.Logger _logger;

    public NLogLogger(Type callerType)
    {
       _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(callerType.Name,callerType);
    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {
       _logger.Info(message);
    }

    public void Warn(string message)
    {
       _logger.Warn(message);
    }
    .....// and others
 }

public class NinjectConfig : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IAppLogger>().ToMethod(p => new NLogLogger(p.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType));
    }
}
```

Comment: But still p.Request.Target returns NULL. Because I'm asking for the service explicitly through IResolution.Get<IAppLogger>(), It keeps returning null.