# NLog.Extensions.Logging and a custom inherited logger

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, nlog

I am elaborating with a custom NLog logger, let's call it MyLogger class. It has own Trace(), Debug(), Info(), .. methods. I would like to use a classic NLog.config file and if possible register manually also some own custom Layout renderers.
Is it possible to do an initial setup in a POC consumer application or somehow extend the NLog.Extensions.Logging to use MyLogger?

Or if unfortunately not, I would like to try to elaborate with a compromise - I mean at least to somehow share the NLog.config between NLog logger bound to the MS logging infrastructure and the MyLogger used in some of my own services. What would a possible setup then look like?

(updated)
to add more details:

- MyLogger class has very similar implementation to the one from the [NLog extending loggers example](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/dev/examples/ExtendingLoggers/InheritFromLogger/Program.cs)
- I have also added IMyLogger interface wit the specific methods signatures
- The console project contains following references

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.3.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.2.8" />
    
    //(configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Poly,..)
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You are free to mix the use of your custom Logger-objects and Microsoft-ILogger-objects. `NLog.Extensions.Logging` integrates NLog as logging-provider for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. That converts Microsoft-ILogger-EventState into NLog-Logger-LogEventInfo (Calling `Logger.Log(LogEventInfo)`-method). It sounds like you want some special integration with your custom NLog Logger, can you update your question with an example of what is wanted?

Comment: Hello Rolf, thanks for your note. As I wrote in different comment,  MyLogger class iherits fro NLogLogger  but with new custom Trace,..Info,Error methods with  sifferent signature. Indeed, I was able to get that mix somehow working (almost good - except one think -services.AddTransient<IMyLogger>((sp) => LogManager.LogFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger<MyLogger>() injects logger with same name to each particular service, so Instead it looks to register each such service with logger manually .  Hm sorry one question is more to the DI container impl. if possible  to somehow extend it?

Comment: (e.g. NIject seems to allow following .Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod(p => NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(p.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType)) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65797518/6208972
 - So it looks  is more question if there is a posibility to extend MS ServiceCollection or use the different more advanced DI container. Here I guess the MS ILogger<T> for some reason generic and this I guess luckily enables to pass the corecct NLoger name. So I wonder if making NLog ILoger generic would also somehow help.

Comment: Other solution could probable be using NLog registered factory in DI Container - Is there planned to be the  NLog IFactory interface?

Comment: (updated) I was thinking about  NLog Logger using Interface with the default implementations, iths morning. But when tried a short time ago, it was clearly showed, it must be a part of the NLog assembly. So I realized it is more for the  authors of the libraries :)

Comment: If you are missing a NLog-ILogger-generic-interface that makes it easy to use NLog ILogger together with Microsoft Dependency Injection while preserving Logger-Name. Then pull-requests are most wellcome: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging . You could also consider creating your own extension-methods (`Debug`, `Trace`, `Info`) for the Microsoft ILogger-interface.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is a [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#:%7E:text=In%20object%2Doriented%20programming%2C%20the,instances%20of%20the%20same%20class.), here is a great [example](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator/csharp/example)!

```
abstract class Decorator : Component
{
    protected Component _component;

    public Decorator(Component component)
    {
        this._component = component;
    }

    public void SetComponent(Component component)
    {
        this._component = component;
    }
```

Follow this logic when the Component is the NLOG and choose how to inject the NLOG (via construtor or via a method).

You can add a SetLogger method to the `MyLogger`, and keep it as a private propetry, then the info() should be somethinkg like (just make sure its not null):

```
    public Method(string message)
    {
        // You custom logic...
        _component.Method(message);
    }
}
```

The usage

```
    MyLogger logger = new MyLogger();
    logger.SetNLog(nlogIntance)

    logger.Info("Hello world.");
```

Comment: I am not sure I can follow - what specific class or interface instance is meant with the nlogInstance?  My questions are related how to setup integration with Microsoft ILogger and my custom logger dependent on the NLog. Meanwhile I came across this doc article: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-GetCurrentClassLogger-and-Microsoft-ILogger article and at the end of it is a comparison of 2 scenarios.  My question is related a kind of hybrid scenario of these two and I am curious about the initial setup code example of that scenario benefiting of sharing the NLog.config

Comment: Perhaps it is also worth to mention, that I have implemented the MyLogger with the inheritance to the NLog Logger class. Another implementation perhaps could be to extend the NLog Logger class with that mentioned Methods.